# Slow Wordpress admin panel with a total query time of 1664ms

Tags: plugins, mysql

I have a problem with my wordpress website, he is realy slow, i installed a debug bar to check queries in the home page, the result is like:

202 queries, and a total query time equal to 1665ms

[image]

The cpu and the ram are in critical use.

[image]

Here is what i tried to do:

- i used Optimize pluginDB to defragment the DB.
- i used ThemeCheck plugin to analyse my theme and clean my theme.
- i am using the w3 total cache plugin with the page and object cache
  enabled.

The installed and necesary plugins are:

- Wordpress SEO by YOAST
- Jetpack service by Wordpress.com
- Contact form 7

Thank you

Comment: How's it do if you have all plugins disabled and use one of the default themes?  Is that same set up slow on a local install?

Answer (score 0):

What host service are you using?  I had the same issue using Dreamhost, where you can adjust the memory limit for the server you are using on the hosts panel.  Doing this solved the issue for us.  Also, a possible issue could be your SQL server, switching to another SQL server may resolve your issue.  Contact your host for more info.